# Как при помощи php внести в БД MySQL данные о времени из формы?

Tags: php, mysql

Суть такова:
Есть форма на сайте. В форме есть поля:
время отхода ко сну
время пробуждения
Это поля формата hh:mm
Нужно занести значение поляей в бд, никак не могу понять какой тип полей в бд должен быть и как передать значение времени в них.

upd1: спасибо, варчаром добавилось. Теперь буду думать как дальше работать с этими данными.

Comment: тип поля в базе даных либо строчный varchar, либо временной time, зависит от ваших дальнейших операций над этой датой.

Comment: В дальнейшем планирую собирать данные времени и вычислять среднее. Тут по ходу возник еще вопрос, если я передам в формате hh:mm, то не вычислю с ходу среднее. Правильно ли я понимаю, что можно будет из бд дергать значения времени, переводить их в милисекунды например и работать с ними?

Comment: @DanDark Зачем в миллисекунды, когда их можно просто переводить в секунды.  Используя функцию explode, получите значение часов и минут и работайте с ними  - $time =  explode(':', time_value);

Answer (score 2):

Не проще-ли хранить в timestamp формате в MySQL? Тогда у вас при работе с базой получается достаточно обширный инструментарий для дат\времени. Можно даже записывать с датой и тогда можно в дальнейшем различные графики строить на этом деле. А складывать данные туда можно просто "yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm" строчкой.